# How do I exit tint2 panel?

Tags: lubuntu, tint2

I am trying out various panels in Lubuntu. I have installed `tint2` alongside `lxpanel` and now I have two. How do I exit `tint2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue a kill signal to it

```
pkill -f tint2
```

or use xkill command in terminal, your cursor will turn to x , and click on the tint2 panel to kill it

Comment: This answer will not be entirely true if @nickolai LEschov has tint2 set to autostart as you would have to do that each time.  If you add your answer and uninstall the tint 2 package it will not keep showing up again.

Comment: @ianorlin  The author of the question asked how to exit tint2. They didn't mention autostart in anyway, and that would make it entirely different question.  I answered what was asked literally. If the case is different, then author needs to specify that in their question